# Failed to compile <modul not found>

Tags: contract-development

please help me

Module not found: Can't resolve 'web3' in 'C:\Users\block\src\components'

i don'k know why ..

### my app.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Web3 from 'web3';

class App extends Component {
  render() 
  }
}

### export default App;

### my package.json

inside i have

### "web3": "1.0.0-beta.46"

[image]

Comment: Did you execute `npm install`? Did it generate an error message?

Comment: oh i just redownload package.json file and reinstall npm install       and then solve the problem!!!! thank you for your answer!!!